# Open Layer, deactive ol.control.Toggle and active another one

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have an ol.control.Bar built as below:

```js
 mainbar = new ol.control.Bar ({ toggleOne: true, group:true });
var me = this;

// Function with its level context
function addButton(level) {
  var levelButton = new ol.control.Toggle({
    html: level,
    onToggle:  function () {
      me.getController().updateFloorplans(level);
    }
  });
  mainbar.addControl (levelButton);
}

 // Insert buttons
var indexFloor = 4;
while(indexFloor > 0){
   addButton(indexFloor);
   indexFloor--;
};
addButton('0');

mainbar.setPosition('bottom-right');
this.map.addControl(mainbar);
```

[image]

I would like to create a function that deactive the buttons in the ol.control.Bar (for example the 3 in the image) and active another button choose by me (ad example the button 2).
How I can do that?

I created this function, but instead to deactivate all the buttons that are active, it remove all the control bar:

```js
 deactiveButtons: function(){
        var self = this;
        self.map.removeControl(mainbar);
     },
```

Comment: Why not just creating a class for the button you want to disable and adding rules for this class into you css ? then you just need to add or remove this class to the button you want to enable/disable

Comment: ol.control.Toggle has a setActive method. Just store buttons in a table and activate it at will: button[3].setActive(false); button[2].setActive(true);

Comment: You can also get controls in the bar: `mainbar.getControls()[3].setActive(false)`